# How to convert sh -c "$(curl -fsSL URL)" to native python

Tags: python, shell, curl, subprocess, exec

I am trying convert the shell command:

`sh -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/foo/install.sh)"`

To native python. I cannot rely on curl being on the system. I start with this to replace `curl`

```
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
from urllib.error import URLError

try:
    urlretrieve("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/foo/install.sh",
                        os.path.expanduser('~/' + 'install.sh'))
except URLError as e:
...
```

What is the best way to then replicate the `sh -c install.sh` portion of the command in native python? I need an interactive shell to install.sh, then for the script to carryon in python. I need a python interactive subprocess with exception handling to execute install.sh

Some examples of subprocess?

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(['sh install.sh'], 
            stdout=subprocess.PIPE, 
            stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
stdout,stderr = p.communicate()
print(stdout)
print(stderr)
```

Another that does not wait for command to complete before writing out

```
import subprocess, sys
cmd = "sh install.sh"
p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
    out = p.stderr.read(1)
    if out == '' and p.poll() != None:
        break
    if out != '':
        sys.stdout.write(out)
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try `os.system()`, that is, after you save the install script in the current directory, then

```
os.system('sh -c install.sh')
```

The script is presumably written in `sh`, so you'll need `sh` (or compatible) to run it.

This uses stdin/stdout, so you can interact with it using the terminal if necessary. When the subprocess terminates, `os.system()` returns its exit code and Python resumes.

(If you're not saving to the working directory, you could use the absolute path to `install.sh`, or change the working directory using `os.chdir()`.)

If you need to automate this interaction in Python, you should probably use `subprocess` instead, it's more powerful, but takes more work to configure.

---

> Yes, I need to run sh and `os.system()` is the easiest way. I would like the script to run unattended and only prompt user if input is needed. I will expand on my question with a subprocess example.

If the script runs and terminates itself on its own in the normal case with no further input, then `os.system()` is enough, even to run unattended, since Python will resume when the script completes. You can also raise an exception for a nonzero exit code, if desired:

```
if os.system('sh -c install.sh'): raise ...
```

Comment: Yes, I need to run sh and `os.system()` is the easiest way. I would like the script to run unattended and only prompt user if input is needed. I will expand on my question with a subprocess example.